# Combination of llncs and html packages, \pdfoutput and \and (backslash and) makes an error

Tags: pdftex, html, lncs

With the following document which combines: `llncs` class, `\pdfoutput`, `html` package and `\and` I get an error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{llncs}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{html}

\title{asdf}
\author{asdf \and asdf} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

My error is:

```
ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.24 

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

The error does not make much sense to me. If I change `llncs` to `article` instead, or if I disable `\pdfoutput` or the `html` package or the use of `\and` I do not get an error.

What is wrong?

The only way around the problem I can think of right now is to avoid using the `html` package. Is there a better way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You must have an old version of `llncs.cls`. Download the latest version at ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip and it would compile without errors.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. With the new package it now compiles without errors.

Comment: Happy about that. The question will now be closed because it sufficed to update your document class to solve the issue. Happy TeXing!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because updating the document class sufficed to solve the issue.